# cannot run border radius with border radius

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, border, radius

Container(

```
     I wrote this code but it didnt run .
```

it do run without borderRadius but with borderRadius doesn't run.

```
      decoration:  BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      border: const   Border(
      left: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.green),
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.red),
      right: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.purple),
      top: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.blue),
       )
      ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are applying `borderRadius` property too while decorating the container which means there cannot be different color's for `bordersides` because they are curved at the edges.

You need to pass same color to each side of you `BorderSide` below code should solve your issue.

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            border: const Border(
              left: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
              right: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
              top: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: thanks for comment but how can make it the way ı want . ı mean colorful .like transitive